# twitter new api v1.1 can not get image url and id

Tags: php, api, twitter

i have problem with twitter new api 1.1

i used to get profile_image_url and id throug this link

http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.xml?screen_name=

now when i enter that page they say they migrated to a anew api application which is

api 1.1

now to get the iformation i need in xml files i tried to use this link :

http://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.xml?screen_name=

but i get this message :

Bad Authentication data

i do not know why ??

i want to get the 
 profile_image_url and id
in xml file like i was doing in api v1 ??

Answer (score 0):

1.1 api calls need to bee authenticated (even for images).  Previously used unauthenticated image retrieval calls will not work - you need to rely on oauth (unless there are other ways that I'm not aware of) to fetch user information (including image).  Use the following for more information;

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/user-profile-images-and-banners  & https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/16425

Hope it helps.